# Hiding internal virtual method

Tags: c#, methods, virtual, internal, method-hiding

I have something as such;

```
internal virtual Draw() { ... }
```

in an compiled assembly. I have classes deriving from this class. Obviously, being outside that specific assembly, I don't have access to overriding this method, or even calling it.

Is it possible to hide this method, since it's not even "visible" from my own assembly?

Is there no way for me to change this behavior at all, to prevent this method from being called or to reroute it?

Comment: Did you want to say `protected internal` instead of `public internal` in your question?

Comment: I think the answer is: just use `private void Draw() {...}`

Comment: You cannot. As this is 'internal' and is getting called only from within the assembly, you cannot prevent the call to this function.

Comment: @farfareast : Sorry, it's only "internal".

Answer (score 1):

If I undrestand you correctly, Using the `EditorBrowsable` attribute like so will cause a method not to be shown in `intellisense`:

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
protected internal virtual Draw() { ... }
```

But you cannot prevent calling it from the same assembly if soem body knows that it is there. (you just can hide it from intellisense and people usually think it doesn't exists)

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you mean your method is `protected internal`, instead of `public internal`, which isn't a valid method signature.

About hiding your method, if you have access to the compiled librarys source code, you could refactor it as being `protected` only inside the assembly so only derived types may override it.

But, "hiding" it is meaningless as nobody outside the assembly itself (which as you say is a 3rd party anyway) can either call it or override it, so there is no point in that being done.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's only `internal`. And no, I do not have access to the original source code.